# Can anyone explain what "std::vector<std::vector<char>> board(3, std::vector<char>(3, ' '));" means

Tags: c++, vector, tic-tac-toe

I came across this code for building a Tic-Tac-Toe game, and have no idea what it means. Can anyone explain in simple terms?

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> board(3, std::vector<char>(3, ' '));
```

context:

```
void drawBoard(const std::vector<std::vector<char>> &board)
{
    for (const auto &row : board)
    {
        for (char cell : row)
        {
            std::cout << cell << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> board(3, std::vector<char>(3, ' '));
    char currentPlayer = 'X';
    int row, col;
    bool gameOver = false;
```

Comment: Break down the parts. `std::vector<char>(3, ' ')` is a vector holding 3 space characters. Given that `board` is a vector holding 3 vectors which each hold 3 space characters.

Comment: Right.  Compare it to this `std::vector<int> example(3, 99);`, which creates a vector of 3 ints and initializes them all to the value 99.  Your example is the same thing.

Comment: It creates a variable named `board` of type `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`.   `board` is intialised using two arguments - `3` and `std::vector<char>(3, ' ')`.    Based on how `std::vector` works (read the documentation!) `std::vector<char>(3, ' ')` creates a vector containing three `char`s which are all initialised to the space character, and `board` contains three `vector<char>`, each with three space characters.

Comment: Yes it is a 2D dynamically allocatable array. However whoever wrote this code failed to make a Board class and encapsulate the 2D array inside this class.  A 2D vector like this is NOT a board, and the drawBoard method should have been a `draw` method on said `Board` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is using one of `std::vector`s [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), twice:

```cpp
constexpr vector( size_type count,
                  const T& value,
                  const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

This constructor is used to initialize the `vector` with `count` number of copies of `value`.

So this ...

```cpp
std::vector<char>(3, ' ')
```

... constructs a `vector` of `char` with three elements, all being initialized to `' '` (space).

In this ...

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> board(3, std::vector<char>(3, ' '));
//                                   ^                    ^   ^
//                                   |                    |   |
//                                   |               ^    +-1-+
//                                   |               |
//                                   +-------2-------+
```

... the `value_type` is `std::vector<char>` and it makes three copies (2 in the graph above) of `std::vector<char>(3, ' ')` (1 in the graph above) which makes a 3x3 game board of `char` all initialized to `' '`.